# Ansible nested and two lists

Tags: ansible

I need to apply ufw rules to 2 sets of machines with a list of ports (same ports for both sets).

What is the correct syntax to do correct the example below?

```
- ufw: rule=allow from_ip={{item[0]}} to_port={{item[1]}}
  with_nested:
  - "{{groups['nodesA']}},{{groups['nodesB']}}" <=== BAD
  - [ '1', '2', '3']#Ports
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to combine the hosts from both groups, just concatenate the lists:

```
- ufw: rule=allow from_ip={{item[0]}} to_port={{item[1]}}
  with_nested:
    - "{{groups['nodesA']+groups['nodesB']}}"
    - [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```